# Can I add a control to a ContextMenuStrip?

Tags: c#, winforms

Is it possible to add a control like CheckBox to ContextMenuStrip?

I want to be able to tick a few options BEFORE I select the menu option.

This what I do now, but I have commented out where I try to add chkBox - as it does not work:

```
DataGridView gridView = sender as DataGridView;
ContextMenuStrip my_menu = new ContextMenuStrip();
int colIndex = gridView.HitTest(e.X, e.Y).ColumnIndex;
Globals.PlotColumnIndex = colIndex;
my_menu.Items.Add("New plot").Name = "New plot";
my_menu.Items.Add("New trades plot").Name = "New trades plot";
my_menu.Items.Add("Add to existing plot").Name = "Add to existing plot";
my_menu.Items.Add("Add to existing plot Y2").Name = "Add to existing plot Y2";
CheckBox chkBox = new CheckBox();
chkBox.Text = "Option 1";
//my_menu.Controls.Add(chkBox);

my_menu.Show(gridView, new Point(e.X, e.Y));

my_menu.ItemClicked += new ToolStripItemClickedEventHandler(my_menu_ItemClicked);
```

Comment: Surely a standard checkable menu item would do?

Answer (score 0):

Using a `ToolStripControlHost` is one option:

```
var cb = new CheckBox();
cb.Text = "Checkbox 1";
var tch = new ToolStripControlHost(cb);
menu.Items.Add(tch);
```

Comment: Can you include ContextMenuSTrip type items as well?